# How to get started on writing a module registry and custom script locator?

Tags: spring-xd

I'm doing some XD deployment (distributed) and dealing with a lot of custom modules is not as smooth as I had hoped.

I've been thinking of adding support to put custom modules on AWS S3. What would it take to implement this? Any pointers or things I need to be aware of.

Is this essentially an implementation of the `ModulRegistry` interface as described in [1]?

In a similar though: i'm dealing with a growing number of customer scripts (for transformers and script processors). Is there an hook to provide storage on S3 as well?

[1] http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/api/org/springframework/xd/dirt/module/ModuleRegistry.html

Comment: How are you dealing with custom modules right now?  I'm also on a custom module-heavy project (albeit we don't use S3 in ours), and we just have the moduleRegistry configured to look in the file system local to the xd-container for module packages.  A cursory internet search says you might be able to mount an S3 bucket to your local filesystem (for each container), at which point it would stand to reason that you can configure SpringXD's xd.customModule.home in servers.yml to point in there, which should accomplish storing your custom modules on S3.

Comment: If at all possible, you should be configuring rather than coding in this instance.  Have a look at The Module Registry under [this section in Spring XD's manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#modules).

Comment: Leveraging docker containers at this point. S3 mount in the container should be possible. I'll play with that option.

Comment: Is there a registry interfaces for custom scripts as well? I don't want to add them in the classpath all the time?

Comment: Are you talking about shell scripts?  You can set a custom property in your servers.yml pointing to your scripts directory and use `${script.directory.property.name}/script.sh` where your scripts are referenced.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. You should post this as an answer not a comment so I can mark it answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to go about this is to mount the S3 bucket to your local filesystem.  Then, modify the `xd.customModule.home` property in `servers.yml` to point to the location in your mounted bucket.  Once this is done, just stash your modules in there (using the directory structure of a typical spring XD modules directory; ie the modules should go into the `<modules>/job`, `<modules>/source`, `<modules>/processor`, and `<modules>/sink` directories depending on the purpose they serve) and spring XD will pick them up.

In terms of getting to your scripts, a solution I used for a similar problem was to define a custom property in `servers.yml` (for the sake of example, I'll call it `script.directory`).  Then, whenever you want to reference a script in that directory, use SPEL to get to it: `${script.directory}/script.sh`.

Comment: I ended up doing an s3 sync (every min) instead of the mount as it was simpler. Still working on the script part but AFAIK, the scripts come also with a config file. Can I dump that in the same folder? From what I have seen, the config was in a separate place (`xd/config/`) than the scripts (`xd/modules/processor/scripts/`).

Comment: Btw. I realised that the custom modules folder does not seem to allow hot-deployment of modules that are packaged as jar files. No idea why. If I drop them into the `${xd.home/modules}` it works fine. Is that normal behaviour?